# How to structure dynamic product browser for SEO?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, meta-tags

I will be building a new website for a client of mine. SEO is very important.
This website will have a product browser for cars, in which visitors can set feature filters to search for products that match those.

For example, a visitor would select a make, model and a price range to view all cars that fall within that range.

Programming is not a problem, also I have quite some experience with SEO.

**How to display this dynamic product list so it helps for SEO? - or at least won't hurt.**

I was thinking of adding a static product browser as well, mainly for SEO purposes. A static list with all products grouped by brand. Canonical product page would be:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/products/%BRAND%/%SHORT_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION%
```

For the product browser index, how to handle:

- url structure (filter-values in querystring, POST or rather as url segments)
- use of canonical url?
- pagination
- etc

Answer (score 1):

You've structured the URLs well, for the pagination you just want to continue with the same structure but in a graphical format, i would look into using breadcrumbs as for each 'step' you would be creating a page, which could be searched for. For instance if some one search for a `Product > Brand` for example `Car > Audi` they would be brought to the Audi page.

With this you'd be able to easily browse through

- `http://www.example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com/products/`
- `http://www.example.com/products/%BRAND%/%SHORT_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION%`

From a UI point of view the most common way this is done is as bellow

[image: breadcrumbs]

With the canonical url I'm not really sure why you'd want that for these pages as each page is going to have its own content, eg `/product/audi` is going to be different to `/product/bmw canonical` URLs tend to be used when the pages are similar in content, like if you had a landing page that was "Buy cars Toyotas in New York" and another landing page "Buy cars Toyotas in California" the pages might have the same content talking about Toyotas, but the only really change is the location. There you would use the canonical URLs or some people also use them instead or as well as 301 redirects between `www`, `non-www`, `/index.html`

With the filter values, I'm not really sure of the best way to approach that, my thoughts on it would be to either just add them in as an additional

`http://www.example.com/products/%BRAND%/%SHORT_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION%/FILTER`

and reflect that as a new tab in the breadcrumbs, or depending on how fine tunable the filters would be you could just filter the list dynamically to hide the not relevant items.